# Insert a while loop

Tags: java

I need to insert a while loop inside the following code so that when the user inputs a wrong password it asks for it again until it's the right password.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PasswordManager {

private static String masterPassword = "secret3";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean correctPassword = false;

    while

    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Password");

    correctPassword = checkPassword(password);

    if (correctPassword == true)

    System.out.println("Correct Password! :)");

    else

    System.out.println("Incorrect Password :(");
}
    private static boolean checkPassword(String password){


    if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(masterPassword))

        return true;

    else

        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: And this is php? and this question has an answer?

Comment: Why _was_ this tagged with PHP? Kinda looks like Java, doesn't it?

Comment: Please change the tag to Java

Comment: Go through the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 1):

My taste is for a terse form like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Password");
    while (! checkPassword(password)) {
        password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Incorrect Password :(\nEnter Password");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Password! :)");
}
```

I dropped the `correctPassword` variable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and I made a mistake by saying it was php it is actually java as most of you guys know. Im new to programming and im taking both php and java, I got confused.